# add Solr search box in views filter

Tags: views, search

I have succesfully installed solr and it is working fine, but my main search in my drupal site is based on views exposed filters, is there a way to add the solr search in views filters, so it interacts with them?

I am using views to setup an advanced search, by exposing filters, i want to add one that uses solr, so in total solr search is used together with views filter and i get corresponding results from files too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Apache Solr Views](https://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_views) module.

Project page says

> In order to get the facet blocks provided by the Apache solr Search
>   Integration Project you need to set up either arguments or exposed
>   filters for the blocks. For instance, you could set up an argument for
>   node type and the Apache Solr Search: Filter by content type block
>   will work.

Comment: i wil try this out later on and come back to you with results.

Comment: Hi, i tried this module but isee no filter in views filters regarding solr.